# How to pass the src value in this HTML via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have pasted the code in

```
    <https://pastebin.com/z8q5cavm>
```

I will be having huge list of rows in the datatable and each row will have a specific href or mp3 file link. However the code always opens the serm.mp3 eventhough whatever i pass in the link.

Can someone help me on how to fix this javascript?

Basically want to change the src of the mp3 file when the media player open on clicking the href link in the datatable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel='manifest' href='/manifest.json'>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon1.png" />
<link rel='manifest' href='/manifest.json'>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar" content="#ffffff" >
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <!--mobile icons-->
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href="images/icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="74x74" href="images/icon-74.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="images/icon-96.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/icon-144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="384x384" href="images/icon-384.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="images/icon-512.png" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
    family=Montserrat:400,700|Oxygen:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Theme Style -->
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../extensions/Editor/css/editor.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<style>
    a.buttons-collection {
        margin-left: 1em;
    }

</style>


 </head>
 <body>



   
<section>
<div style="margin: 20px;">
  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
       
          <tr>
              <th>S No</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Listen</th>
              <th>Download</th>
             
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td >Mp31</td>
             
              <td ><a href="media/mp3/test1.mp3" title="Click To Listen"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
              data-value="media/mp3/test1.mp3">Listen <svg class="bi bi-caret-right-square-fill"  width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm5.5 10a.5.5 0 0 0 .832.374l4.5-4a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.748l-4.5-4A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 4v8z"/>
              </svg> </td>
                            <td> </td>
          </tr>

       
                    <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td >Mp32</td>
             
              <td ><a href="media/mp3/test2.mp3" title="Click To Listen"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onClick=""
              data-value="media/mp3/test2.mp3">Listen <svg class="bi bi-caret-right-square-fill"  width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm5.5 10a.5.5 0 0 0 .832.374l4.5-4a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.748l-4.5-4A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 4v8z"/>
              </svg> </td>
                            <td></td>
          </tr>


      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>S No</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Listen</th>
            <th>Download</th>
           
         </tr>
       </tfoot>
    </table>
   </div>
 </section>


<!--MP3 modal-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"  >
  <!-- Scrollable modal -->
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">MP3</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-body" >
            <div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><audio controls preload="metadata" style=" width:450px;">
                <source src="media/mp3/serm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
              </audio></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  <!-- loader -->
  <div id="loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"><circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/><circle class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#f4b214"/></svg> 
 </div>



  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],

        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
        responsive: true,
       

    } );
 
    t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
} );</script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"> 
 </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"> 
 </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"> 
 </script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
</code>
```

Thanks

Comment: Add some relevant code - Not ideal to add images - Stack-over flow is not a free coding service you need to provide us your efforts to achieve this or if you are stuck at something ? Please do your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) or provide a minimal example of your work. Read here how to ask a [GOOD question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edited. Please kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have hard coded the src value to serm.mp3, you are getting that.

you need add following script , to make use data-value which you are sending to modal.

```js
    <script>
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        
            var value = e.relatedTarget.dataset.value;
            $('audio').attr('src', value);
        });
    </script>
```

here is the demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel='manifest' href='/manifest.json'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon1.png" />
    <link rel='manifest' href='/manifest.json'>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar" content="#ffffff" >
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--mobile icons-->
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href="images/icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="74x74" href="images/icon-74.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="images/icon-96.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/icon-144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="384x384" href="images/icon-384.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="images/icon-512.png" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Oxygen:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Theme Style -->
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../extensions/Editor/css/editor.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        a.buttons-collection {
            margin-left: 1em;
        }

  </style>


  </head>
  <body>
    
  
 
        
  <section>
    <div style="margin: 20px;">
      <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            
              <tr>
                  <th>S No</th>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Listen</th>
                  <th>Download</th>
                  
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td >Mp31</td>
                  
                  <td ><a href="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" title="Click To Listen"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
                  data-value="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3">Listen <svg class="bi bi-caret-right-square-fill"  width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm5.5 10a.5.5 0 0 0 .832.374l4.5-4a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.748l-4.5-4A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 4v8z"/>
                  </svg> </td>
                                <td> </td>
              </tr>
   
           
                        <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td >Mp32</td>
                  
                  <td ><a href="media/mp3/test2.mp3" title="Click To Listen"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onClick=""
                  data-value="media/mp3/test2.mp3">Listen <svg class="bi bi-caret-right-square-fill"  width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm5.5 10a.5.5 0 0 0 .832.374l4.5-4a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.748l-4.5-4A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 4v8z"/>
                  </svg> </td>
                                <td></td>
              </tr>
   
   
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>S No</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Listen</th>
                <th>Download</th>
                
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
</section>

  
    <!--MP3 modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"  >
      <!-- Scrollable modal -->
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">MP3</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
              <div class="modal-body" >
                <div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                  <audio id="player" controls><source src="" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
                  </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   
  

  <!-- loader -->
  <div id="loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"><circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/><circle class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#f4b214"/></svg></div>
  


  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 


    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    
    <script>$(document).ready(function() {
        var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": 0
            } ],
            "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],

            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5'
            ],
            responsive: true,
            

        } );
     
        t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
            t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i+1;
            } );
        } ).draw();
    } );</script>
    
    <script>
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        
            var value = e.relatedTarget.dataset.value;
            $('audio').attr('src', value);
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The mp3 files - test1.mp3 or test2.mp3 is not opened in the mp3 player. Please help me with a working sample...

Comment: For that you need add actual url's of audio in the table list page, I have updated the answer with some sample mp3 for test1.mp3 only. Check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. Awesome...Is it possible to contact you via email Allabakash ???